# Converting pandas columns of chemical formulas to SMILES

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, rdkit, cheminformatics

I’m wondering if there’s a way to get SMILES strings starting from a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
Formula.   Band_Gap(eV)
He         3.1
NaCl       1.2
NO2        3.5
...        ...
```

Basically, I want to perform a regression task (predicting band gap values for a ton of compounds) using some graph neural network architecture (GraphConv) but I don’t have access to SMILES information. Any suggestion on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any other columns other than Formula? You cannot get SMILES from the formula as you have no indication of how the atoms connect to each other.

Comment: Got it Sir.. and no unfortunately I don’t have any other columns for my problem.

Comment: We have a lot of SMILES questions here too: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=smiles

Answer (score 1):

There is a package to perform such kind of task, "pysmiles". I dunno much abt it. I hope it might help you.

[Pysmiles](https://pypi.org/project/pysmiles/)

Comment: This package looks like it can read/write SMILES strings. The OP is looking for a way to generate SMILES from the data they have in the table, so I don't see how this package would be useful in this case

Comment: We have a lot of SMILES questions here too: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=smiles